# When posting a comment, is it possible to insert any formatting?

Tags: support, comments

Am I missing something?  Or do comments not allow for any formatting (bold, bullets, hyperlinks, etc)?

Comment: See the little "help" link next to the comment edit box? Tells you exactly what you can do. There is a very limited amount of formatting (bold, italics, code and links).

Comment: Check out [the FAQ about comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) which covers this and a few other topics. (You can also find formatting information by clicking the "help" link under the "Add Comment" button while you're writing a comment.)

Comment: ***Absolutely not!***

Comment: @Oded, thanks for those.  I now see the help link, and the formatting instructions (including "Learn more") underneath.  Helpful.

@ Kendra, same to you.